# objective c : hand over delegate to other class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I am here confronted with a certain problem. I have a protocol which states a method, that returns the datasource for my tableviews. The datasources are generated by one class, for 3 tableviews. If you tap on one cell, you get to the next tableview with a different source and so on (I think you get the point).

Everything works fine for the first tableview, but as I hand over the deletage to the next tableview I still do not get the datasource for the second. Do I have to release the delegate at a certain point? And if I have to, how do I get it back, when the navigationbarbuttonitem is tapped on...?

Tell me if you have any ideas.

EDIT:

```
if ([Where isEqualToString:@"System"])
{
    if ([exchangeDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getNewDataSourceForSystem:)]) 
    {
        [exchangeDelegate getNewDataSourceForSystem: [controlDelegate setBranchNavigation:What]];
    }
}
    else if ([Where isEqualToString:@"User"])
    {
        if ([exchangeDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getNewDataSourceForUser:)]) 
        {
            [exchangeDelegate getNewDataSourceForUser: [controlDelegate setLeafNavigation:What]];
        }
}
if ([exchangeDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getNewDataSourceForCostumer:)]) 
{
    [exchangeDelegate getNewDataSourceForCostumer: [controlDelegate setRootNavigation]];
}
```

each respondToSelector goes to a different class.

EDIT:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Costumers getNewDataSourceForSystem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a3b0e0'

Thats what I get as an exception when I leave out  `respondsToSelector:@selector`.

Comment: Can you show some code? Is your generator class able to distinguish which data source to return?

Comment: if you see the source, you would probably like to hit me :-) the problem is, first I got a exception, because it was not able to find the right class where to send the data to, so I added respondsToSelector:@selector to my code, but now nothing happens at the second class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it seems, using a singleton is the proper way to store my data for my views:

- I created a singleton.
- The singleton holds my 3 different data-arrays.
- The delegate sends the new arrays to the singleton.
- I am fetching the data from the views via the singleton.

As simple as it is ... thank you guys for your inspiration :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you called `-[UITableView reloadData]` to inform it about invalidation of its current state?

And have you overloaded you delegate setter method in order to also fetch and set the new datasource and delegate as needed? Probably something like this:

```
-(void)setDelegate:(id<MYDelagate>)delegate;
{
    myTableView.dataSource = [delegate tableViewDataSource];
    myTableView.delegate = [delegate tableViewDelegate];
    _delegate = delegate;
}
```

Comment: I have to look into that issue, will tell you when I figured out :-)

Comment: --> Each view has a delegate and therefore I programmed a property with a synthesize, which will be handed over as the User selects a cell in the view, and I set the delegate with the property ... will also post code soon of that.

Comment: so, that I understood it right, I am able to give my delegate properties. That's a new concept for me (I am programming obj-c now for 2 weeks).

Comment: well I am know thinking, I will take another shot, trying to redesign my whole project, maybe I am able to bypass my problem with a singelton class ... we will see :-)